# Help to decide the partition to install ubuntu

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, windows, windows-7

I have a PC running with windows 7 ultimate 64 bit version with 4 gig Ram. I have a 320 gig hard disk , in which I have allocated 120 gig for windows 7, 100 gig for NY files(named ashwin in windows) and rest 80-90 gig partitioned but empty NTFS partition.Now where do I install Ubuntu so that windows and data is safe.

I got the option install with windows I selected it , it then shows select drive(SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) -320.1 GB ATA WDC WD3200AAJS-6) and allocate driver by dragging the divider below which shows 66.5gb and 59.3 GB respectively. Which one do I go with?

I clicked advance partitioning it shows five devices:

```
device   , type, m.point ,size.(mb), used(mb).........
/dev/sda1, NTFS,          104 ,      35 (windows 7 loader)
/dev/sda2, NTFS,          104752,    23604
/dev/sda3, NTFS,          125829,    10161
/dev/sda5, NTFS,          89382,     3221
```

when I checked size in properties it showed

name of drive according to windows,

```
            used.Gb,   free,   total.
ashwin,     10.2,      115.7,  125.8 
c drive,    23.6,      81.1,   104.8
new volume, 92.6mb,    89.3,   89.4
```

except mentioned everything in gigabytes.ignore the last dots.
 I want to install it in new volume or using that space how do I do it?

Explain in detail I'm a beginner.

Comment: Delete the Empty NTFS partition using Windows. Ubuntu installation will find the empty space and create all the partition it needs there.

Comment: @user6818616 I did as u said I clicked dual boot with windows it automatically installed and now I get option boot with windows or Ubuntu but when I clicked windows it says read error Ctrl + alt + del to restart. what do I do?

Comment: The error on Windows boot sounds like a Windows problem. You may have to fix Windows boot or reinstall. I don't knows enough to help with that. When you fix Windows, it may mess up the Ubuntu boot loader called GRUB. Please search Ask Ubuntu and if you don't find the answer, ask a new question.